# Serializing .MinValue of value types (C#) in ASP.NET Web API 2 to null

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to serialize .MinValue of value types (C#) in ASP.NET Web API 2 to null when passing to the client. When the client sends a value with null I would like get the .MinValue for value types back on the server.

I am using Json.Net for Json serialization and deserialization. Further I need the same for URI parameters and maybe formdata. The following types i need: short, int, long, float, double, decimal, DateTime

Things I tried:

- One solution is to work with nullable types. But on the server i prefer to work with not nullable types because the business logic layer is working with value types and in the data access layer they are converted to DBNull if they are .MinValue.
- I wrote a JsonConverter for DateTime (derived from IsoDateTimeconverter) to handle the DateTime.MinValue as null and vice versa. This works fine, but I am not sure how to do with Numbers because they don't have any JsonConverter implementations in Json.Net or I can't find them.
- For URI-Parameters I will try some Implementation of IModelBinder

Is there a built in way in Json.Net to handle my needs which I have not found?

How can I overwrite the Number-Serialization (int, decimal, ..) in Json.Net?

Any other idea to satisfy my needs...

Comment: You can write your own converter derived from `JsonConverter`. Override `CanConvert`, `ReadJson` and `WriteJson` in it and add `[JsonConverter(typeof(NullToIntMinJsonConverter))]` to your properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a custom converter to do this:

```
public class ValueTypeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private static List<Type> SupportedTypes = new List<Type>
    {
        typeof(short),
        typeof(int),
        typeof(long),
        typeof(float),
        typeof(double),
        typeof(decimal),
        typeof(DateTime)
    };

    private static Dictionary<Type, object> MinValues;

    static ValueTypeConverter()
    {
        MinValues = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

        foreach (Type type in SupportedTypes)
        {
            MinValues.Add(type, GetMinValue(type));
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, 
        Type objectType,
        object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        object value = reader.Value;

        value = value ?? MinValues[objectType];
        value = Convert.ChangeType(value, objectType);

        return value;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return MinValues.ContainsKey(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {        
        object minValue = MinValues[value.GetType()];

        if (object.Equals(value, minValue))
        {
            value = null;
        }

        writer.WriteValue(value);
    }

    private static object GetMinValue(Type objectType)
    {
        FieldInfo minValueFieldInfo = objectType.GetField("MinValue");

        return minValueFieldInfo.GetValue(null);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new[] { new ValueTypeConverter() }
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/WPhJr5